# Node js cpanel post request not working, get request is working fine and get post request are working fine on localserver

Tags: node.js

I have namecheap shared hosting. And when i hit a post request it return me an html in response like page not found. But the same code on local server is working perfectly. While get request are working on live server.
Thanks in advance to every one.

Comment: You were able to host node js in Cpanel? I thought this wasn't possible yet

Comment: no it didnt successfull i tried my best  so i purchased the digital ocean machine and deployed the node js server there.

Comment: Yeah, node js doesnt have the support yet. Digital ocean , aws, heroku has it. Heroku is free for 4projects tho